# Populating an array with values that fall below the averange and calculating the variance

Tags: arrays, function, vba, range

I am trying to select those values from a one-dimensional range of data that fall below the average.

Would this code be right? I think there is a problem with how I place them into the array BelowAvg...

```
 Function MoyBelow(data As Range) As Variant     
Dim i As Integer     
Dim N As Long     
Redim BelowAvg() As Variant     
Dim Varian As Double     
Dim Somcar() As Variant          

N=WorksheetFunction.Count(data)     
RendMoy=WorksheetFunction.Average(data)          

    For i=1 To N         
        If data.Cells(i).Value < RendMoy Then             
            BelowAvg(i).Value = data(i).Value         
    End If         
    NB = BelowAvg.Count                  

         For j=1 To NB             
             SumSq= SumSq + (BelowAvg(i) - RendMoy)^2        
         Next j
    Next i


         Varian = SumSq/NB     

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that returns an array of doubles that contains the below average cells in a range:

```
Function GetBelowAverageValues(data As Range,RangeAverage As Double) As Double()
Dim FilteredRangeValues As Variant
Dim BelowAverageValuesCount As Long
Dim BelowAverageValues() As Double
Dim i As Long

If data.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    MsgBox "only one cell"
    Exit Sub
End If
data.AutoFilter 1, "<" & RangeAverage
FilteredRangeValues = data.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
BelowAverageValuesCount = UBound(FilteredRangeValues)
ReDim BelowAverageValues(1 To BelowAverageValuesCount)
For i = 1 To BelowAverageValuesCount
    BelowAverageValues(i) = FilteredRangeValues(i, 1)
Next i
GetBelowAverageValues = BelowAverageValues
data.AutoFilter
End Function
```

It uses the `AutoFilter` function and SpecialCells property to filter and select just the relevant cells. For your uses you could call it something like this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim DataRange as Range
Dim RangeAverage As Double
Dim BelowAverageValues() As Double
Dim i as Long
Dim Varian As Double

Set DataRange = Selection
RangeAverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(DataRange )
BelowAverageValues = GetBelowAverageValues(DataRange ,RangeAverage)
    For i=1 To Ubound(BelowAverageValues)            
        SumSq= SumSq + (BelowAverageValues(i) - RendMoy)^2        
    Next i
Varian = SumSq/NB
End Sub
```

This is mostly tested, but may have an error somewhere. The main function is tested and worked for me.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please accept it, since it answered the question.